# Escape character for FIQL or RSQL

Tags: java, cxf

I am using the cxf-rt-rs-extension-search for converting a fiql query to jpa query. If the parameter has a I in it then it fails with an Exception Unexpected closing bracket at position.

Does the FIQL specification mention any escape character? A simple way to reproduce the issue is

```
SearchCondition<JPAEntityClass> sc = new FiqlParser<JPAEntityClass>(JPAEntityClass.class).parse("name==hi(");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to implement my own parser that escapes selectively.